# How to convert hex string to octal string in java

Tags: java, string

I am converting a string into hexadecimal string and i want to convert that into octal string

I am doing it as follows

```
String s="I found the reason 2 days ago i was too bussy to update you.The problem was that the UDHL was missing. I should have added 06 at the beginning.  it all works fine.For some reason I thought kannel adds this by itself (not very difficult...), but now I know it doesn't...";


String hex = String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, s.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Output is

```
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
```

I need to convert hex to octal string. I tried like this

```
String octal = Integer.toOctalString(Integer.parseInt(hex,16));
```

But as expected it gave me number format exception as hex string have some characters in it.

I want to know how can i conver hex string to octal string.

Comment: just out of curiosity: what's the point in doing this ?

Comment: What are you expecting at the end? A single base-8 integer representing the whole string or a sequence of base-8 integers representing each byte?

Comment: the number is much larger than an integer...

Comment: Its required in my project  @Marged

Comment: Yes i know it doesnt fit in integer whats the way around plz tell me @assylias

Comment: I want a sequence of base-8 integers representing each byte @Phylogenesis

Comment: Then use your `s.getBytes()` and do the conversion on each byte individually.

Comment: Can you give me an example to make it clear

Comment: @kirti Something like [this](http://ideone.com/EpDNMZ)?

Comment: I think this is it :) Thanks @Phylogenesis.. I think you should post it as answer

Comment: @kirti being a requirement is a valid right to exist but what I meant was what needs to be achieved by this ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments, you want to convert each byte individually and convert them to octal:

```
String s     = "My string to convert";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");

for (byte b : bytes) {
    String octalValue = Integer.toString(b, 8);

    // Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your input (`String hex`) is to big to be stored in a single integer.

3 hex digits correspond to 4 octal digits. So split your input string in chunks of three digits, use the conversion you already figured out, and concatenate the outputs.